# How can I insert a string into a 2D array inside of a struct in C dynamically?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am currently attempting to insert a string argument into a 2D array inside of a struct. The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to use realloc to dynamically increase the size of this 2D array inside the struct. Currently it is set up to use Malloc so I can test it for a single argument, which still is giving me a segmentation fault.

Here is the struct I am working with:

```
typedef struct SimpleCommand {
    // Available space for arguments currently preallocated
    int _numberOfAvailableArguments;
    // Number of arguments
    int _numberOfArguments;
    // Array of arguments
    char **_arguments;
}SimpleCommand;
//The struct is declared in Main as follows:
struct SimpleCommand _currentSimpleCommand = {._numberOfAvailableArguments = 0, ._numberOfArguments = 0, ._arguments = NULL};
```

The struct is then passed into a function thats job is to strcpy an argument into the 2D array inside the simple command struct.

```
//insert argument into simple command
void insertArgument(struct SimpleCommand command, char * argument ){
    //malloc some space for the argument
    command._arguments = malloc(strlen((argument)));
    //copy argument into array
    strcpy(command._arguments[command._numberOfArguments], argument);
    command._numberOfArguments++; //added an argument
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but here goes my deduction:

```
malloc allocates memory.
realoc realocates memory preserving, when possible, the data previously stored.
```

pseudo (not compiled)

```
int count = 10;
Thing * things = malloc(count * sizeof(Thing));
things[0] = athing;
// things[0] ... [9] is ok

// need more memory
count += 10;
Thing * things = realloc(things, count * sizeof(Thing));
// things[0] ... [19] is ok
// things[0] still hold athing
```

As you pointed out, you are using a 2D array. The line below looks suspicious:

```
command._arguments = malloc(strlen((argument)));
```

You are allocating size for a char* and storing it in a char**!!

In your problem you need to allocate space for your array of arguments and space to copy your arguments (if I understand what you are trying to do). One will need malloc as its size does not change. The other will need realloc as more arguments are added.

I hope this helps you complete your homework without giving you the full solution.